# Angular filter to add " before and after variable content

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML / Angular code:

```
<blockquote>
  {{testimonial.text}}
</blockquote>
```

How can I create a filter, named blockquote, that would add a " before and after {{testimonial.text}}?

Something like:

```
{{testimonial.text | blockquote}}
```

Would render as:

```
"testimonial text content"
```

In opposing to my current code which renders:

```
testimonial text content
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a filter which adds " on start and end of the input:

```
.filter('blockquote', function() {
  return function(value) {
    return '"' + value + '"';
  }
})
```